# How a constant current of 23 mA flows from the capacitor when the transisitor turned on?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, bjt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPNaeW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The following is a circuit I got from a research paper and I am trying to analyze it. The inverter is a high speed inverting buffer whose output is always one. The circuit starts functioning when the inverter sends an output of zero. I will quote the sentences in the paper about the idle conditions (When inverter output is one)

> "The output of inverter biases Q1 Such that its emitter Voltage is higher than the base voltage of Q3, thus cutting off the collector current of Q3.
>   Capacitor C6 will have been charged to 5 volts through R17
>   with a time constant of about 5 us"

When the inverter ouput is zero,

> "The inverter
>   generates a fast falling edge and quickly turns off Q1 thus
>   turning on Q2.The collector
>   of Q2 draws a constant 23 ma from C1, thus discharging it
>   at the uniform rate of 0.1 volts per nanoSecond"

My doubts :

1) How turning off Q1 can turn on Q2?

2) When Q2 is turned on, how the collector become constant taking 23 mA from C1?

Comment: 1 & 2/ The circuit is a so called "long tailed pair" I suggest you read up on that. Also the discharge statement is only partly true because at some point the discharge will stop.

Comment: @Oldfart But how can I calculate it to be 23 mA? Even if it is 23 mA, how can the capacitor current be constant? I can't see any circumstance I the circuit where linear discharging of capacitor is possible.. !!

Comment: why is V3 labeled as -5 V? ... is the polarity correctly oriented?

Answer (score 3):

When the inverter output goes to 0V, Q1 effectively disappears from the circuit (the E-B junction is reverse biased) so you can just analyze Q2. When it is high, Q2 is off and it effectively disappears, so the capacitor charges through R1 towards +5V.

With the inverter output at 0V, the lower side of R4 is at -5V and the emitter is at about -0.6V if the transistor is active, so the emitter current (and the collector current assuming it's active) are about 4.3V/0.2K = 22mA.

There's a bit of current flowing through the 22K resistor which changes with the voltage and some other non-ideal things going on so it's not going to be exactly constant, but there's a region where the current is more-or-less constant so there is a more-or-less constant slope downward of about 100mV/ns at the collector of Q2, from the initial charge of the capacitor (5V or so) down to perhaps -500mV, after which the transistor saturates.

Answer (score 2):

Because Q2 base is at 0V, it is turned on when Q2 emitter goes to about -0.7V. Q1 is controlled so that emitter is higher than -0.7V or it lets voltage to drop to point where Q2 turns on.

Q2 is connected as constant current sink, and because Q2 base is at 0V, there is about -0.7V on emitter and thus about 4.3V over the 200 ohm resistor, 4.3V/200 is about 22mA and it is constant as supply voltage or Vbe voltage does not depend on capacitor voltage. Sure the current is less when capacitor is empty.